# Problems filling an array with numbers

Tags: forth

I created an array and wanted to fill it with numbers. I used a loop but it spoils the previous item when goes to next:

```
create mass 2 2 * CELLS ALLOT

: [!] ( value index array -- ) +  ! ;

: show
  4 0 DO mass I + ? LOOP ;

: fill
  4 0 DO I I mass [!] show CR LOOP ;

fill

3 3 mass !
show
```

...so `show-word` gives me this step by step:

```
0 0 0 0

256 1 0 0

131328 513 2 0

50462976 197121 770 3
```

moreover, after `3 3 mass !` the `show-word` gives me this:

```
3 0 0 0  ok
```

I don't understand how to work with arrays and what happens in my loop and why after `3 3 mass !` it gives me not what I get in loop..  please help.

(I understand that forth section is all in my questions now... sorry)

Answer (score 4):

That `+` word in `[!]` and `show` will simply add the index as a number to the address, producing new address that is not aligned to the cell size. This is why you damage the content of `mass`, and also you don't see its content with `show` correctly.

Without changing much the stack effects of your words, the fix could look like this:

```
create mass 2 2 * CELLS ALLOT

: [!] ( value index array -- ) swap cells +  ! ;

: show
  4 0 DO mass I cells + ? LOOP ;

: fill
  4 0 DO I I mass [!] show CR LOOP ;

fill

3 3 mass [!]
show
```

Note the `cells` word that will transform the index into correctly sized offset into the array.

edit: in the last manual assignment use your `[!]` word, or transform the index 3 into correct offset, as mentioned by @dave_thompson_085 in the comments.

Comment: Also the final, 'manual' store should use `[!]` -- or else `3 3 cells mass + !`